# On the boundedness properties of the mapping $f\to |f|^{\frac12}$ on homogeneous Sobolev space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $\Delta f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\Delta$ denotes the  Laplacian. Then I’m asking whether or not we have the following estimates
$$
\|\nabla|f|^{\frac12}\|_{L^2}\leq C\|\Delta f\|_{L^1}^{\frac12}.
$$
i.e., does the mapping $f\to |f|^{\frac12}$ send functions from $\dot{W^{2,1}}$ to $\dot{W^{1,2}}$ ?

It seems that a paper of W. Sickel (Boundedness properties of the mapping $f\to |f|^{\mu}$, $0 <\mu< 1$ in the framework of Besov spaces) has shown that the inhomogeneous version of the inequality above is indeed true. However I'm not able to get that paper for now, and more importantly, I'm not sure whether the method there will also work for the case I'm concerning.

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: I don't think this can be true. Take $f$ harmonic (and bounded, say) on a large subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, Thanks, But the inhomogeneous version is true according to Sickel's paper I mentioned, which sounds a little bit strange.

Comment: @anonymous, I don't think so. I think both sides scale like $\lambda$

Comment: In your case, the right hand side also has $\lambda^{\frac12}$.  I thought you mean the fowllowing scaling: $f(x)\to f(\lambda x)$, then both sides scale like $\lambda$

Comment: (I've removed my superfluous comments): I claimed earlier that the two sides scaled differently but they do not; @Hannes was kind enough to point out my error to me, thanks for that!